# No entities inside datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial

Everything works fine except after I run my AppEngine project there are no entities listed. I went to check on `http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin` and there are no entities listed.

I only receive the following message:

> Datastore has no entities in the Empty namespace. You need to add data programatically before you can use this tool to view and edit it.

The class is the same like from the tutorial:

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class CheckIn {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    private String placeId;
    private String userEmail;
    private Date checkinDate;

    public Key getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getPlaceId() {
        return placeId;
    }
    public void setPlaceId(String placeId) {
        this.placeId = placeId;
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }
    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    public Date getCheckinDate() {
        return checkinDate;
    }
    public void setCheckinDate(Date date) {
        checkinDate = date;
    }
}
```

I tried to search for available solutions but I can't find anything useful. What can you suggest to me to check? Thanks!

Comment: Have you run any code that would actually write an entity to the data store.

Comment: @TimHoffman, I followed all the steps from that tutorial. Isn't this writing entity to the datastore: 
`Select Google ->Generate Cloud Endpoint Class. The <classnameEndPoint.java> class is generated. Where the classname prefix is the name you assigned in step 2.
In the Package Explore r, right-click on the App Engine project name.
Select Google ->Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library. The lib<classname>endpoint library is created in the mobile client.`

Comment: The above only generates the client library. You will now have to link the client library in your mobile application (android or iOS) and then invoke the call to insert the record.